# React router - How to route to a page with specific post id

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

Im trying to route to a link to a page with a specific id.
When I want to edit a post I click on the edit link and it should be redirected to the edit page with the specific post id.
in app.js I have given the route like this.

```
<Route  path="/edit/${registrations._id}">
                  <Edit/>
              </Route>
```

then in the page with the link I have written it like this.

```
 <Link to="/edit/${registrations._id}" className="edit" >Edit </Link>
```

but this not route to the page with specific id.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is what you need:

```js
<Route  path="/edit/:id">
  <Edit/>
 </Route>
```

And then in the Link provide the path to /edit/${registrations._id}

Also remember if you are using template string sintax ${id} to wrap it with `` instead of with ""